# Input pattern regexp validation, JS add commas, allow user add commas and validate it

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation, backbone.js

I have search a lot, I can make almost all tasks separately, but all together ...
So, I have input with type="text"

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[1-9]|^[-,0-9]{2,18}$" class="form-control commas-decimal-points" id="tot-uniques-display-<%%= model.adPartnerId %>" placeholder="eg. 100,000,000" name='network_data[display][total_monthly_uniques]' value="<%%= model.display.total_monthly_uniques  %>"/>

pattern="^[1-9]|^[-,0-9]{2,18}$"
```

This pattern validate only for number, not more than 14 digits, not allow start from "0".

**I must allow user input numbers, it must start from number > 0 and be not more than 14 numbers, user can input commas in special places *OR* if user input only numbers I must add commas by JS. If user input commas by itself I must validate it according to pattern.**

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
100,000
1,000,000
10,000,000
100,000,000
1,000,000,000
10,000,000,000
100,000,000,000
1,000,000,000,000
10,000,000,000,000
```

I have such function in my backbone view:

```
inputEventOnInput: function (e) {
    var me = this;

    // skip for arrow keys
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

    // format number
    me.$el.find(':input[type="text"]').val(function(index, value) {
      return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });

  },
```

It fires on "input" event and add commas when user input only numbers.
If user input 10000000 it will be replaced by 10,000,000 in input.

**How I can define that use input commas, then validate this commas according to a pattern, and fire HTML5 :invalid event on wrong commas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following for validating whether commas are according to the pattern:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3}){0,3})$|^([1-9]\d?(,\d{3}){4})$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oK8rZ3/2)

You can use this [Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc2jsuLq/) for handling all three cases.